# Make new variant keyboard layout available in Settings?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I’ve edited the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` to add a new variant keyboard layout.  However, it's not showing up as available to add in Settings > Text Entry. How can I get this list to refresh, so that the new variant shows up?

What I’ve tried so far (based on advice found elsewhere):

- restart;
- delete the `*.xkm` files in `/var/lib/xkb` (cached compiled keyboard layouts).

Is there some table where I need to add an entry for the new variant?  Or is there some other cache I need to clear?

I’m running 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you gave the new layout a name other than 'gb' (which I recommend, otherwise your changes might get reset in an update). In that case you need to add a `<layout>` element to the list `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` – just look at the other entries. [This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) refers to the file as `evdev.html`; so my information may be outdated (I'm still using 12.04 LTS).

BTW, my updated `evdev.xml` once got reset, too, and I faced unexpected trouble when only the Greek keyboard layout was available at the login screen. Luckily, I had been wise enough to save my changes in a home directory copy.