# How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to copy a keyboard layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and change it and then produce a new layout from it.

How can I add a new keyboard layout (named e.g. "mylayout")?

**Update #1:**

Files I changed to add a new layout:

- `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/irwinxp` (originally the same as `ir`):

  ```
  // Iranian keyboard layout

  ////////////////////////////////////////
  // Persian layout,
  // based on
  // Information Technology – Layout of Persian Letters and Symbols on Computer Keyboards
  // ISIRI 9147 – 1st Edition
  // Institute of Standards and Industrial Research of Iran
  // http://www.isiri.org/UserStd/DownloadStd.aspx?id=9147
  // http://behnam.esfahbod.info/standards/isiri-keyboard-9147.pdf
  //
  // Author: Behnam Esfahbod <behnam@esfahbod.info>
  //

  default  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "pes" {
      name[Group1]= "Persian";

      include "ir(pes_part_basic)"
      include "ir(pes_part_ext)"

      include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3nnb4)"
      include "level3(ralt_switch)"
  };


  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "pes_keypad" {
      name[Group1]= "Persian (with Persian Keypad)";

      include "ir(pes_part_basic)"
      include "ir(pes_part_keypad)"

      include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3nnb4)"
      include "level3(ralt_switch)"
  };

  partial hidden alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "pes_part_basic" {

      // Persian digits
      key <AE01> { [ Farsi_1, exclam,     grave           ] };
      key <AE02> { [ Farsi_2, 0x100066c,  at          ] };
      key <AE03> { [ Farsi_3, 0x100066b,  numbersign      ] };
      key <AE04> { [ Farsi_4, 0x100fdfc,  dollar          ] };
      key <AE05> { [ Farsi_5, 0x100066a,  percent         ] };
      key <AE06> { [ Farsi_6, multiply,   asciicircum     ] };
      key <AE07> { [ Farsi_7, Arabic_comma,   ampersand       ] };
      key <AE08> { [ Farsi_8, asterisk,   enfilledcircbullet  ] };
      key <AE09> { [ Farsi_9, parenright, 0x100200e       ] };
      key <AE10> { [ Farsi_0, parenleft,  0x100200f       ] };

      // Persian letters and symbols
      key <AD01> { [ Arabic_dad,      Arabic_fathatan,    degree      ] }; // 2: Arabic_sukun
      key <AD02> { [ Arabic_sad,      Arabic_dammatan,    VoidSymbol  ] }; // 2: Arabic_dammatan
      key <AD03> { [ Arabic_theh,     Arabic_kasratan,    0x13a4      ] }; // 2: Arabic_kasratan
      key <AD04> { [ Arabic_qaf,      Arabic_fathatan,    VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AD05> { [ Arabic_feh,      Arabic_comma,       VoidSymbol  ] }; // 2: Arabic_damma
      key <AD06> { [ Arabic_ghain,    Arabic_semicolon,   VoidSymbol  ] }; // 2: Arabic_kasra
      key <AD07> { [ Arabic_ain,      Arabic_fatha,       VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AD08> { [ Arabic_heh,      Arabic_hamza_above, 0x100202d   ] }; // 2: Arabic_shadda
      key <AD09> { [ Arabic_khah,     bracketright,       0x100202e   ] };
      key <AD10> { [ Arabic_hah,      bracketleft,        0x100202c   ] };
      key <AD11> { [ Arabic_jeem,     braceright,     0x100202a   ] };
      key <AD12> { [ Arabic_tcheh,    braceleft,      0x100202b   ] };

      key <AC01> { [ Arabic_sheen,    Arabic_fatha,       VoidSymbol  ] }; // 2: Arabic_hamzaonwaw
      key <AC02> { [ Arabic_seen,     Arabic_damma,       VoidSymbol  ] }; // 2: Arabic_hamzaonyeh
      key <AC03> { [ Farsi_yeh,       Arabic_kasra,       Arabic_alefmaksura ] }; // 2: Arabic_yeh
      key <AC04> { [ Arabic_beh,      Arabic_shadda,  VoidSymbol  ] }; // 1: Arabic_hamzaunderalef
      key <AC05> { [ Arabic_lam,      0x10006c0,  VoidSymbol  ] };// 2: Arabic_hamzaonalef
      key <AC06> { [ Arabic_alef,     Arabic_maddaonalef, 0x1000671   ] };
      key <AC07> { [ Arabic_teh,      Arabic_tehmarbuta,  VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AC08> { [ Arabic_noon,     guillemotright,     0x100fd3e   ] };
      key <AC09> { [ Arabic_meem,     guillemotleft,      0x100fd3f   ] };
      key <AC10> { [ Arabic_keheh,    colon,          semicolon   ] };
      key <AC11> { [ Arabic_gaf,      quotedbl,       quotedbl    ] }; // 2: Arabic_semicolon

      key <AB01> { [ Arabic_zah,      Arabic_kaf,     VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AB02> { [ Arabic_tah,      0x1000653,      VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AB03> { [ Arabic_zain,     Arabic_jeh,     VoidSymbol  ] };
      key <AB04> { [ Arabic_ra,       Arabic_hamzaonwaw   ,0x1000656  ] }; // 2: Arabic_superscript_alef ٰ
      key <AB05> { [ Arabic_thal,     0x100200c,      0x100200d   ] };
      key <AB06> { [ Arabic_dal,      Arabic_hamza_above, Arabic_hamza_below  ] };
      key <AB07> { [ Arabic_hamzaonyeh,   Arabic_hamza,       ellipsis    ] }; // 1: Arabic_peh
      key <AB08> { [ Arabic_waw,      greater,        comma       ] };
      key <AB09> { [ period,      less,           apostrophe  ] };
      key <AB10> { [ slash,       Arabic_question_mark,   question    ] };

      key <TLDE> { [ 0x100200d,       division,       asciitilde  ] };
      key <AE11> { [ minus,       Arabic_tatweel,     underscore  ] };
      key <AE12> { [ equal,       plus,           0x1002212   ] };
      key <BKSL> { [ Arabic_peh,      bar,            0x1002010   ] }; // 1: backslash
  };

  partial hidden alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "pes_part_ext" {

      // Persian and ASCII digits
      key <AE01> { [ 0x10006f1,   exclam,     grave,          1   ] };
      key <AE02> { [ 0x10006f2,   0x100066c,  at,         2   ] };
      key <AE03> { [ 0x10006f3,   0x100066b,  numbersign,     3   ] };
      key <AE04> { [ 0x10006f4,   0x100fdfc,  dollar,         4   ] };
      key <AE05> { [ 0x10006f5,   0x100066a,  percent,        5   ] };
      key <AE06> { [ 0x10006f6,   multiply,   asciicircum,        6   ] };
      key <AE07> { [ 0x10006f7,   Arabic_comma,   ampersand,      7   ] };
      key <AE08> { [ 0x10006f8,   asterisk,   enfilledcircbullet, 8   ] };
      key <AE09> { [ 0x10006f9,   parenright, 0x100200e,      9   ] };
      key <AE10> { [ 0x10006f0,   parenleft,  0x100200f,      0   ] };
  };

  partial hidden alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "pes_part_keypad" {

      // Persian digits and Mathematical operators
      key <KPDV> { [ division,    XF86_Ungrab ] };
      key <KPMU> { [ multiply,    XF86_ClearGrab  ] };
      key <KPSU> { [ 0x1002212,   XF86_Prev_VMode ] };
      key <KPAD> { [ plus,    XF86_Next_VMode ] };

      key <KPEN> { [ KP_Enter ] };
      key <KPEQ> { [ equal    ] };

      key <KP7>  { [ KP_Home, 0x10006f7   ] };
      key <KP8>  { [ KP_Up,   0x10006f8   ] };
      key <KP9>  { [ KP_Prior,    0x10006f9   ] };

      key <KP4>  { [ KP_Left, 0x10006f4   ] };
      key <KP5>  { [ KP_Begin,    0x10006f5   ] };
      key <KP6>  { [ KP_Right,    0x10006f6   ] };

      key <KP1>  { [ KP_End,  0x10006f1   ] };
      key <KP2>  { [ KP_Down, 0x10006f2   ] };
      key <KP3>  { [ KP_Next, 0x10006f3   ] };

      key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,   0x10006f0   ] };
      key <KPDL> { [ KP_Delete,   0x100066b   ] };
  };


  ////////////////////////////////////////
  // Kurdish Layout

  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "ku" {
      include "tr(ku)"
      name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Latin Q)";
  };

  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "ku_f" {
      include "tr(ku_f)"
      name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, F)";
  };

  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "ku_alt" {
      include "tr(ku_alt)"
      name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Latin Alt-Q)";
  };

  ////////////////////////////////////////
  // Kurdish Soranî Bahdînî (Arabic) keyboard layout,
  // based on the Kurdî Soranî Bahdînî keyboard from KurdITGroup
  // which is based on National Iranian Keyboard Standard (ISIRI 2901:1994),
  // with additions.
  //
  // Copyright (C) 2006 Erdal Ronahî, published under the GPL v2
  //
  // Special copyright note: author explicitly permitted to license this 
  // layout under MIT/X11 license, for details see
  // https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9541
  //
  // Author: Erdal Ronahî  <erdal.ronahi@gmail.com>
  //
  // Kurdish Arabic-Latin Layout for Soranî

  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "ku_ara" {
      name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Arabic-Latin)";

      // Other 3-Level symbols
      key <TLDE> { [ 0x100200d,       division,       asciitilde  ] };
      key <BKSL> { [ backslash,       bar,            ccedilla, Ccedilla  ] };

      // Digits
      key <AE01> { [ 1,   exclam,     0x10006f1,  grave       ] };
      key <AE02> { [ 2,   at,         0x10006f2,  at      ] };
      key <AE03> { [ 3,   numbersign, 0x10006f3,  0x100066b   ] };
      key <AE04> { [ 4,   dollar,     0x10006f4,  0x100fdfc   ] };
      key <AE05> { [ 5,   percent,    0x10006f5,  0x100066a   ] };
      key <AE06> { [ 6,   asciicircum,    0x10006f6,  multiply    ] };
      key <AE07> { [ 7,   ampersand,  0x10006f7,  Arabic_comma    ] };
      key <AE08> { [ 8,   asterisk,   0x10006f8,  enfilledcircbullet  ] };
      key <AE09> { [ 9,   parenright, 0x10006f9,  0x100200e   ] };
      key <AE10> { [ 0,   parenleft,  0x10006f0,  0x100200f   ] };
      key <AE11> { [ minus,       Arabic_tatweel,     underscore  ] };
      key <AE12> { [ equal,       plus,           0x1002212   ] };

      key <AD01> { [         Arabic_qaf,            X,  q,  Q ] };
      key <AD02> { [         Arabic_waw,            X,  w,  W ] };
      key <AD03> { [          0x10006d5,   Arabic_heh,  e,  E ] };
      key <AD04> { [         Arabic_ra ,    0x1000695,  r,  R ] };
      key <AD05> { [         Arabic_teh,   Arabic_tah,  t,  T ] };
      key <AD06> { [          0x10006cc,    0x10006ce,  y,  Y ] };
      key <AD07> { [  Arabic_hamzaonyeh, Arabic_hamza,  u,  U ] };
      key <AD08> { [         Arabic_hah,   Arabic_ain,  i,  I ] };
      key <AD09> { [          0x10006c6, Arabic_hamzaonwaw,  o,  O ] };
      key <AD10> { [          0x100067e,  Arabic_theh,  p,  P ] };
      key <AD11> { [ bracketright,    braceright, ucircumflex, Ucircumflex    ] };
      key <AD12> { [ bracketleft,     braceleft,  scedilla, Scedilla  ] };

      key <AC01> { [ Arabic_alef, Arabic_maddaonalef, a, A    ] };
      key <AC02> { [ Arabic_seen,     Arabic_sheen,   s, S    ] };
      key <AC03> { [  Arabic_dal,     Arabic_thal,    d, D    ] };
      key <AC04> { [  Arabic_feh, Arabic_hamzaunderalef,  f, F    ] };
      key <AC05> { [   0x10006af,     Arabic_ghain,   g, G    ] };
      key <AC06> { [  Arabic_heh,     0x100200c,  h, H    ] };
      key <AC07> { [   0x1000698, Arabic_hamzaonalef, j, J    ] };
      key <AC08> { [   0x10006a9,     Arabic_kaf, k, K    ] };
      key <AC09> { [  Arabic_lam,     0x10006b5,  l, L    ] };
      key <AC10> { [  Arabic_semicolon,   colon,      ecircumflex, Ecircumflex    ] };
      key <AC11> { [  apostrophe,     quotedbl,   icircumflex, Icircumflex    ] };

      key <AB01> { [ Arabic_zain,     Arabic_dad, z, Z    ] };
      key <AB02> { [ Arabic_khah,     Arabic_sad, x, X    ] };
      key <AB03> { [ Arabic_jeem,     0x1000686,  c, C    ] };
      key <AB04> { [   0x10006a4,     Arabic_zah, v, V    ] };
      key <AB05> { [ Arabic_beh,      0x1000649,  b, B    ] };
      key <AB06> { [ Arabic_noon, Arabic_tehmarbuta,  n, N    ] };
      key <AB07> { [ Arabic_meem, Arabic_tatweel,     m, M    ] };
      key <AB08> { [ Arabic_comma,    greater,    comma       ] };
      key <AB09> { [ period,      less,       apostrophe  ] };
      key <AB10> { [ slash,       Arabic_question_mark,   question    ] };

      include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3)"
      include "level3(ralt_switch)"
  };

  // EXTRAS:

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Generated keyboard layout file with the Keyboard Layout Editor.
  // For more about the software, see http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor
  //
  // Version 0.2, fixed AD09.
  //
  // Layout by Ernst Tremel, http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9365469&postcount=32
  // Creation of this file by Simos Xenitellis.

  partial alphanumeric_keys
  xkb_symbols "ave"
  {
      name[Group1] = "Avestan";

      key <AB01> { [ U10B30,         U10B32 ] }; //   
      key <AB02> { [ U10B11,         U10B12 ] }; //   
      key <AB03> { [ U10B17,          UE102 ] }; //   
      key <AB04> { [ U10B2C,         U10B13 ] }; //   
      key <AB05> { [ U10B20,         U10B21 ] }; //   
      key <AB06> { [ U10B25,         U10B27 ] }; //   
      key <AB07> { [ U10B28,         U10B29 ] }; //   
      key <AB08> { [ U10B3C,         U10B39 ] }; //   
      key <AB09> { [ U10B3E,         U10B3D ] }; //   
      key <AB10> { [ U10B3F, periodcentered ] }; //  · 

      key <AC01> { [ U10B00,         U10B01 ] }; //   
      key <AC02> { [ U10B2F,         U10B31 ] }; //   
      key <AC03> { [ U10B1B,         U10B1C ] }; //   
      key <AC04> { [ U10B1F,         U10B16 ] }; //   
      key <AC05> { [ U10B14,         U10B15 ] }; //   
      key <AC06> { [ U10B35,          UE100 ] }; //   
      key <AC07> { [ U10B18,         U10B24 ] }; //   
      key <AC08> { [ U10B10,          UE101 ] }; //   
      key <AC09> { [ U10B2E,          UE103 ] }; //   
      key <AC10> { [ U10B3B,         U10B3A ] }; //   
      key <AC11> { [ U10B1D                 ] }; //  

      key <AD01> { [ U10B22,         U10B23 ] }; //   
      key <AD02> { [ U10B33,         U10B34 ] }; //   
      key <AD03> { [ U10B08,         U10B09 ] }; //   
      key <AD04> { [ U10B2D,         U10B26 ] }; //   
      key <AD05> { [ U10B19,         U10B1A ] }; //   
      key <AD06> { [ U10B2B,         U10B2A ] }; //   
      key <AD07> { [ U10B0E,         U10B0F ] }; //   
      key <AD08> { [ U10B0C,         U10B0D ] }; //   
      key <AD09> { [ U10B0A,         U10B0B ] }; //  
      key <AD10> { [ U10B1E                 ] }; //  
      key <AD11> { [ U10B06,         U10B07 ] }; //   
      key <AD12> { [ U10B02,         U10B03 ] }; //   

      key <AE01> { [ U10B78                 ] }; //  
      key <AE02> { [ U10B79                 ] }; //  
      key <AE03> { [ U10B7A                 ] }; //  
      key <AE04> { [ U10B7B                 ] }; //  
      key <AE05> { [ U10B7C                 ] }; //  
      key <AE06> { [ U10B7D                 ] }; //  
      key <AE07> { [ U10B7E                 ] }; //  
      key <AE08> { [ U10B7F                 ] }; //  

      key <BKSL> { [ U10B04,         U10B05 ] }; //   
      key <LSGT> { [ U10B04,         U10B05 ] }; //   
  };
  ```
- Part of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` containing all modifications:

  ```
  ...
     <layout>
        <configItem>
          <name>ir</name>

          <shortDescription>fa</shortDescription>
          <description>Persian</description>
          <languageList>
            <iso639Id>per</iso639Id>
          </languageList>
        </configItem>
        <variantList>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>pes_keypad</name>
              <description>Persian (with Persian Keypad)</description>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Latin Q)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_f</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, F)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_alt</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Latin Alt-Q)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_ara</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Arabic-Latin)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
        </variantList>
      </layout>    
      <layout>
        <configItem>
          <name>irwinxp</name>

          <shortDescription>fa</shortDescription>
          <description>Persian-WinXP</description>
          <languageList>
            <iso639Id>per</iso639Id>
          </languageList>
        </configItem>
        <variantList>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>pes_keypad</name>
              <description>Persian (with Persian Keypad)</description>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Latin Q)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_f</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, F)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_alt</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Latin Alt-Q)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
          <variant>
            <configItem>
              <name>ku_ara</name>

              <shortDescription>ku</shortDescription>
              <description>Kurdish (Iran, Arabic-Latin)</description>
              <languageList>
                <iso639Id>kur</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
            </configItem>
          </variant>
        </variantList>
      </layout> 
      <layout>
        <configItem>
          <name>iq</name>
  ...
  ```

But now, with these changes the new `Persian-WinXP` layout does not obey `irwinxp` and `irwinxp` is igored. Instead `ir` controls `Persian-WinXP`.

**Update #2:**

Unity has a problem with my new layout. The new layout icon is dark. But it works well.

[image: dark layout icon]

**Note**: I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You can simply add a variant. I did that here: http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the steps needed to create a new keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-a-new-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Creating custom keyboard layout

For example, I'm looking to add a new modified *English (international AltGr dead keys)* US layout with swapped `r`,`R` & `t`,`T`. I will name it *XY swapped:RT English (international AltGr dead keys)*.

1. Create new symbols file:

   `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/xy`

   ```
    default  partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "basic" {

       name[Group1]= "XY swapped:RT English (international AltGr dead keys)";

       include "us(altgr-intl)"

    // my custom changes:

       key <AD04> { [        t, T,           ediaeresis,   Ediaeresis      ] };
       key <AD05> { [        r, R,           thorn,        THORN           ] };


       include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    };
   ```

   `include "us(altgr-intl)"` means it inherits all key from that layout only key overridden here.

   You may use [**Keyboard Layout Editor**](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor) which is a GUI program that helps create or edit XKB keyboard layouts. Thanks to @Glutanimate
2. Add the new layout declaration to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` (copy & modify `us` layout section)

   Reference: [Make new variant keyboard layout available in Settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463919/make-new-variant-keyboard-layout-available-in-settings)

   `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`

   ```
    ...
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>xy</name>

        <shortDescription>en</shortDescription>
        <description>XY swapped:RT English (international AltGr dead keys)</description>
        <languageList>
                 <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
                 <iso639Id>fra</iso639Id>
                 <iso639Id>ger</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList>
      </variantList>
    </layout>
    ...
   ```
3. Delete xkb cache.

   ```
    sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm
   ```

   > Notes:

   > To load changes to the layouts menu simply restart gnome-keyboard-preferences; relaunching the window manager should not be necessary.

   > There is a change in Ubuntu version 13.10 which causes the keyboard settings cache to not refresh after files in "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols"  are modified. It looks like changes just don't get applied. To force the cache refreshing a one should delete *.xkm files from "/var/lib/xkb".

   > <sup>**Reference:** [Howto: Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)</sup>

   or

   ```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
   ```

   <sup>**Reference:** [Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout)</sup>

   [image: Custom keyboard layout]

### Reply to fix OP modifications

- (**Update #1 wrong parent layout**) You have modified `xkb_symbols "pes_part_basic"` which is in `irwinxp` file: that's ok.

  but `xkb_symbols "pes"` in `irwinxp` file still:

  ```
    include "ir(pes_part_basic)"
  ```

  which should be:

  ```
    include "irwinxp(pes_part_basic)"
  ```
- (**Update #2 custom icon**) If `<shortDescription>en</shortDescription>` changed to `<shortDescription>xy</shortDescription>`. So the new layout will distinct from `En` and it will appear as `Xy`.

  Most probably there will be no icon for it in `ubuntu-mono`. Then the indicator will dynamically generate new one which may not follow current theme.

  1. Copy any layout icons for dark/light mono themes:

     ```
      sudo cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-keyboard-En.svg /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-keyboard-Xy.svg
      sudo cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22/indicator-keyboard-En.svg /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22/indicator-keyboard-Xy.svg
     ```
  2. SVG files are just XML. Open then for editing and change text value from `En` to `Xy`:

     ```
      sudo nano /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-keyboard-Xy.svg
      sudo nano /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22/indicator-keyboard-Xy.svg
     ```

     Example:

     ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
      <svg width="22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="22">
       <defs>
        <mask id="m">
         <rect y="0" x="0" style="fill:#fff" height="22" width="22"/>
         <text y="15.5" x="5" style="font-size:12;font-family:Ubuntu;font-weight:500;fill:black">Xy</text>
        </mask>
       </defs>
       <rect style="fill:#dfdbd2" mask="url(#m)" rx="2" height="20" width="20" y="1" x="1"/>
      </svg>
     ```
  3. Update theme cache:

     ```
      sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-*/
     ```
  4. Logout/login

     [image: new layout with custom icon]

### Other Helpful References

- [How to modify a keyboard layout in Linux](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) (thanks to @Rmano)
- [Building an XKB Keyboard](http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php/Building_an_XKB_Keyboard) (thanks to @Glutanimate)
- Another well documented post that adds more examples like level 5 shift. See [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/510024/26246)

Comment: Now it is a more complete guide than https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions. Thanks. btw, I wonder if I need to add the new layout name to other files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/`.

Comment: yep @user69453 , :). As it works no need. They seem having same information in different formats, most probably a migration process from one format to other, we may expect disappearance  of some of them next releases. Not sure, if I get any reference for that I will add it.

Comment: Great answer! Just a quick tip: You can use [KeyboardLayoutEditor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor) to quickly generate custom symbols files.

Comment: Adding a flag picture is also necessary for KDE. An option in KDE can show country flag instead of layout label. For my artificial layout label is shown instead of a flag.

Comment: Just for completeness sake: [Here's another very helpful resource about XKB configuration on Linux](http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php/Building_an_XKB_Keyboard)

Comment: How would one go about changing <Super_R> to behave as <Menu>? My own solution was to create a new alias in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` : `alias <MENU> = <RWIN>;` But that means I do not have the option to switch it using layout as in your solution...(which I think is much better :)

Comment: @eugenevd, it seems to me you are looking for to map  just few keys.  It is easier  using `xmodmap` (see http://askubuntu.com/a/257497/44179 ) then creating new layout.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using variations of the above answer for a number of years but things started to break with newer versions of Ubuntu and possibly due to the switchover to Wayland so I looked for another way.

It appears a more convenient and cleaner (since it's all in userspace) way of specifying keyboard layout customisations has been introduced.  This has been tested on 22.04 LTS and 21.10 under GNOME/Wayland; it doesn't work under X.org.

Here's an example that remaps the PrtSc ("print screen") key as the "menu" key.  I find this useful on my ThinkPad keyboard, as it has this less useful (IMHO) former key in lieu of the latter.

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.config/xkb/{symbols,rules}
cd ~/.config/xkb
cat > rules/evdev << EOF
! option = symbols
  custom:prtscmenu = +custom(prtscmenu)

! include %S/evdev
EOF
cat > symbols/custom << EOF
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "prtscmenu" {
  key <PRSC> { [ Menu ] };
};
EOF
```

In the above, we've created a couple of files called `rules/evdev` and `symbols/custom` in the `.config/xkb` directory of our home directory.  Note: no need for `sudo` or modifying any system file.

In those files, we've defined a custom option, which we've called `prtscmenu` (you can use what you like, just replace all occurrences of the string), and finally we've used the "familiar" XKB syntax to override the `<PRSC>` ("print screen") key as desired.  The syntax is the same as the one used in the accepted answer.

Finally, in order to apply this option (or disable it), on top of whichever keyboard happens to be loaded, one just needs to run:

```bash
# apply custom layout:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['custom:prtscmenu']"
# disable custom layout:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
```

These can easily be set as aliases to make things even easier.

A couple more points:

- You can have multiple such customizations defined and apply them separately (the `xkb-option` GSettings above accepts an array)
- Unlike the accepted answer, this won't generate a wholly separate layout.  So let's say you switch between different layouts in your workflow - say US and your own locale - you could apply the same `prtscmenu` customization atop each layout.

Source & credit: https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/02/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-1.html

Comment: using the synthetic "MENU" key that you define above works great for picking AUTOCORRECT entries in Google Docs; however, it stopped working in GMAIL... do you know why?

Also was wondering what the `alias <MENU> = COMP ; ` line means in the `xkb` file

Comment: if we use your method of putting the xkb modifiers in `$HOME/.config`  does that make the keyboard layout change if we `sudo -s` to root in a shell?

Comment: @Jonathan: configuration in `$HOME/.config` affects the user running the Desktop Environment (GNOME), which is typically the user you log in as.  If you run `sudo -s` in a terminal window, you'll be escalating your privileges as `root` in that window but the GNOME DE will still be running as your user account so the modification will continue to apply to the complete environment, regardless of your terminal window running a `root` session.  It's probably not advisable to run the DE (ie: login) as `root`.

Comment: Yesss! I've been wanting a pure-userspace way to swap my laptop's PgUp/PgDn and Home/End keys, but have been having a bear of time finding anything. Your answer gave me all the missing pieces to the puzzle; thank you!

Comment: Can't get this to work for me, but my system uses X11 (not wayland)