# How to add some special characters to a layout

Tags: keyboard, games, layout

Today, I bought a gaming keyboard which has an *English* layout. The problem here is that I am *Portuguese* and this keyboard doesn't have `~` and `ç`.

Is there any way that I can include those keys in my new keyboard layout?

Comment: Check [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu/511142#511142) or [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a Portuguese keyboard layout it automatically makes these characters for you. The fact that your keyboard doesn't have a Portuguese layout is not a problem.Only you have to remember which character stands for which.

Click on the language icon on the right top corner and you can add Portuguese layout.