# Own keyboard layout

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

I'm working with us and de layouts.
Is it possible to edit/add some symbols to us layout? I would like to have some German letters on us layout:

- AltGr+o=ö, AltGr+Shift+o=Ö
- AltGr+s=ß,
- AltGr+a=ä, AltGr+Shift+a=Ä
- ALtGr+u=ü, AltGr+Shift+u=Ü

AltGr is right Alt.

Is it possible to add this letter to us layout like this?

- OS: Xubuntu 12.04
- Xfce 4.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition and http://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Community-driven manual for this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Comment: Link-only answers are not welcome.

Comment: Thanx. That link helped.

Comment: @UNIm95 Did it work?

Comment: Yes. This link helped me to change keyboard layout. But it would be better if we had some GUI for this.

Comment: who will be given the bounty?

Comment: If nobody posts nothing better, I'll assign the bounty to @madneon

Comment: @madneon: Please, update your answer with a good explaination. Link-only answers are not welcome