# Russian ЯШЕРТЫ keyboard on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout

I need to have a russian phonetic ЯШЕРТЫ keyboard on Ubuntu. I have ЯВЕРТЫ but I need ЯШЕРТЫ. I couldn't find it in text entry settings. Should I download it from somewhere or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: I don't see it either. Maybe you want to [create a custom keyboard layout](http://askubuntu.com/q/482678).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/)