# Creating a custom text entry input source (keyboard layout) based on an existing one

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

How can I create a modified copy of an existing text entry layout?

To be more specific, I'd like to add the parenthesis **(** **)** and **#** symbol to the *Armenian (alternative phonetic)* layout by sacrificing some other symbols.

I know about the possibility of mapping a key to a different one, but that won't work as I need this for one layout only. Also that would be rather a dirty hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new custom keyboard layouts is pretty easy if you know what to do. There is already a [detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition) on how to set up a new keyboard layout. You will only need to add entries for the changes you need.