# Change of key promted change of numeric layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

In Ubuntu 22.04, I changed two keys in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols se`

After a reboot, the keys got remapped correctly. But after a second reboot, it seems my entire numeric row has changed functionality. I think the US layout is chosen, even though it seems it isn't.

In `/var/lib/xkb` there is only one file: `README.compiled`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> seem to work like before, but <kbd>L-Alt</kbd> and <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> now seem to function like the same key and with changed behaviour. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Gr</kbd> or <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> used to return a paragraph when combined with section key that is to the left of <kbd>1</kbd>. But now, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Gr</kbd> changes window focus.

`cat /etc/default/keyboard` returns

```
XKBLAYOUT="se,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll"
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> should return `=` but instead returns `)`

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> should return `?` but instead returns `_`

Pressing <kbd>User</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (my version of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) to change to Cyrillic Russian keyboard does nothing. The system says that the keyboard is switched to the other language, but I cannot type anything in Russian.

My only remaining guess is that I edited more than I thought in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols se`, but I cannot see how that would do these changes.

Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and then rebooting changed nothing.

No startup applications has been added during this.

[System keyboard settings still shows Swedish Russian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06N1M.png)

*How can I undo this change?*

**EDIT**

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

returns

`[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'ru')]`

and

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

returns

`['grp_led:scroll']`

Changing language at top right in menu bar is possible, but the changes have no effect. The same keys are shown regardless if `lang = ru` or `lang = se`

**EDIT 2**

Reset changes with Gunnar's help:

`sudo apt reinstall xkb-data`

The reset helped to revert the changes.

However, I still face the problem that the layout seems to change when I try to change keybindings.

I tried creating a new layout instead of changing the current one by following [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition).

I managed to create a copy of my keys but after two reboots the entire layout changes to an us one.

**Update**

Tried following [this tutorial](https://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/). The changes made to

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols se
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules evdev.lst
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules evdev.xml
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules base.lst
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules base.xml
```

remain after several reboots. The unwanted to switch to us-layout only happens after at least two reboots. However, now the reset doesn't help. The unwanted changes persist after `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and a reboot.

I fount [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1lOF.png) in my system settings for keyboard now when I pressed `View Keyboard Layout` for the Swedish keyboard. It is not a Swedish keyboard layout. It looks like the typical us keyboard, no? Displaying the [same window for the Russian keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4v50.png) shows Cyrillic, but I cannot type anything in Russian despite this.

Noticed I could do `sudo setxkbmap` and `sudo setxkbmap -layout` for `us` and `ru`, but not for `se`, which returned this error: `Error loading new keyboard description`

Using `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data` helped reset everything so that I at least can do `sudo setxkbmap se`

Comment: Did the reset make a difference?